# In Rust, what is gained from making a function 'async'?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, async-await, concurrency, rust-tokio

I know that an `async` function will return a Future, and that calling `.await` on that future will repeatedly call `poll()` on it until it completes, but I don't understand the difference between that and a regular function.
Does it give any benefit to make a function `async` if it already works without it?

I have two versions of code that do the same thing. Consider the "experiment" functions as main functions running with `#[tokio::main]`.

One version calls a regular function to create code that can run asynchronously with `tokio::spawn()` ([playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6905a3cc784cf526c5fc75cdc0c3e038), though it seems to not show the output well):

```rust
pub async fn experiment1() {
    spawn_task(1);
    spawn_task(2);

    loop {
        println!("3");
        tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
    }
    
}

fn spawn_task(n: i32) {
    tokio::spawn(async move {
       loop {
           println!("{n}");
           tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
       }
    });
}
```

The output of this is below (3 numbers print out every second, this is 3 seconds worth of output). Each loops runs concurrently.

```
3
1
2
3
2
1
3
1
2
```

The other version uses `async` and `await` ([playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5a33c03e27090969bae39eea3ddf4a37), though it seems to not show the output well):

```rust
pub async fn experiment3() {
    spawn_task(1).await;
    spawn_task(2).await;

    loop {
        println!("3");
        tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
    }
    
}

async fn spawn_task(n: i32) {
    tokio::spawn(async move {
       loop {
           println!("{n}");
           tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
       } 
    });
}
```

The output of this is below (3 numbers print out every second, this is 3 seconds worth of output). Each loops also runs concurrently.

```
3
1
2
3
1
2
3
2
1
```

Comment: Since in both examples you use `tokio::spawn` to spawn asynchronous tasks without `.await`ing them, you don't need to mark `spawn_task` as `async`. The "benefit" of making a function `async` is to make it possible to do `.await` inside the function body.

Answer (score 3):

When you only run synchronous code like in your examples the only
difference is that you change the return type from plain `T` to
`impl Future<Output = T>`. You might want to use this to use otherwise
synchronous functions in places where an asynchronous function is
expected.

The real benefit comes in when you actually use asynchronous code
inside of it:

```rust
fn fun() {
    // this is not allowed because we're not inside an async block or function
    tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
}
```

The above function is not allowed, to make it work we have to declare
it as an `async` function:

```rust
async fn fun() {
    // we can use await here
    tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
}
```